# Promql filter out time series with value in label same like in another metric dynamicaly

Tags: prometheus, metrics, promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

Assuming I have two different metrics with different labels names but the same a group of values :

```
metric1{label1="some_values_the_same_as_in_metric2"}  val examples: val1 val2 val3
metric2{label2="some_values_the_same_as_in_metric1"}  val examples: val2 val3
```

Now I want to query metric1 with label1 but filter out all metrics with the same value as in metric2 label2

I know I can `metric1{label1!=~"val2|val3"}`

but what if i have 300 values in metric1 and 200 in metric2 and these can change over time?
how to filter it out dynamically?

tried many things like this:
`metric_name1 unless metric_name2 on(common_label) group_left`
but without success

Comment: to match `metric1` and `metric2` values, the comparison label should be the same (`common_label` ok, but not `label1` and `label2`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is in correct direction. It's just that `on()` clause needs label common for both metrics, but based on your example, they are not.

This is not a problem though: `label_replace` can help us here.

```
metric_name1
 unless on(label1)
 label_replace(metric_name2, "label1", "$1", "label2", "(.*)")
```

Here, I copy label `label2` into `label1`, and then use it in `unless` to exclude all the metrics with matching `label1`.

You don't need `group_left` since `unless` with `on` clause doesn't change left operand's labels set (unlike `and` with `on` clause).

Comment: Thank you! That is now my query which has that clue i use lable_join instead of label_replace as I need both labels later on :

kube_deployment_spec_replicas unless on(deployment) label_join(kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_spec_min_replicas, "deployment", "", "horizontalpodautoscaler", "(.+)")